# Which version does make system use if there are several versions of a library

Tags: make

Let's say we have freetype library already installed in /usr/lib64/libfreetype.so whose version is 1.4 and there is another version of this library that we have compiled and installed in /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.so. How does the build system (make) know which version to use when we are build a software that requires freetype?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR version: it depends.

- OS: there may be an OS specific environment (`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) configuration file or command (such as `ldconfig(8)`) that registers the paths used to search for libraries.
- build system: there may be [environment variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html) such as `LDFLAGS` or command line flags or configuration file settings; `mutt` has `--with-curses=[dir]` for when the system (or user) has ncurses under a custom path. These depend on the build system (or even then flavor of `make`) and may need to be manually written into the autoconf or cmake files.
- post build configuration: tools such as `patchelf` (if available) allow different libraries to be selected or the search path altered.

Comment: `ldconfig` is from the 1980s and was withdrawn with the conversion to `ELF`. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` does not control the search for version numbers but rather to directories. So in case that(as usual)  the different releases are in the same directory, this does not help.

Comment: if `ldconfig` was withdrawn then why did I need to fiddle around with `ldconfig` on RedHat Enterprise Linux 7 to get NVIDIA/CUDA/tensorflow software compiled?

Comment: Well, Linux did take the SunOS-4.0 sources for the dynamic linker from the FreeBSD people and did never upgrade to the recent ELF based version that appeared in 1989 with SVr4.

Answer (score 0):

`libxxx.so` usually is a symbolic link to the shared library file that includes the version in the name.

If you link using `-lxxx`, then this `libxxx.so` file is used.

If you like to link against another version, you need to specify the full path name of the library.